# PHP - Sharing a static class variables with instances from multiple pages

Tags: php, class, object, static

I am a PHP developer an i have a class that is included in almost every page of my project. Now the object the class that I create each time is the same per in all of the pages, although I have an object that I need to have in each and every one of the objects, regard the page their in. So my question is, can I have a class that have a static variable that is sherd between instances from different pages?

NOTE - I have to create the object only when the first instance is created because you cannot declare new in the variable

example:

page name - class.php

```
<?php
    class foo{
        var $a;
        public static $b;

        function foo($a){
            $this->a = $a;
            if(!self::$b) self::b = new bar("c");
        }

        public static function update_static(){
            self::$b = new bar("c2");
        }
  } 

  class bar{
        var $c;

        function foo($c){
            $this->c = $c;
        }
  } 
?>
```

Now i Have two different pages.

page 1.

```
<?php
    include('class.php');
    $new_foo = new foo("a");
    var_dump(foo::$b); //or var_dump($new_foo::$b)
?>
```

page 2.

```
<?php
    include('class.php');
    $new_foo = new foo("a");
    foo::update_static();
?>
```

I want that when you run the first page then the second and then the first again the optup on the first page will be:
first run -

```
object(bar)(1){["c"]=>string(1) "c"}
```

second run after running the second page -

```
object(bar)(1){["c"]=>string(1) "c2"}
```

now I know I am declaring the object inside the static variable only when the first instance is created but I wonder if their is any way to do that instances in more then one page will share the same static object.

Comment: PHP is a server side language (meaning once it finishes compiling, it forgets everything), you cannot commit an action from view to view. Try looking into using JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You could but likely wouldn't by using static variables.  It can be done by having a web server that reuses the same memory, like some implementations in ReactPHP.

However, most web servers are set up to treat PHP requests as "new" processes that do not share any memory, so variables and properties from previous requests would not be available.  The ways to maintain state for these requests would be using persistent storage (databases), caches, sessions (server side), or cookies (client side).

Comment: Sessions and cookies are going to be per user, not global.